# nedit: Segmentation fault Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I installed & tried to open `nedit` in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version, I faced this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried in debugging mode:

```
$ gdb nedit
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/nedit 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555dcb99 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555555dcb99 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff76c0e7c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff76c1818 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff76c1c68 in _XtCreateWidget ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff76f0f50 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff76f1383 in XtVaCreateManagedWidget ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
#6  0x000055555559b3dc in ?? ()
#7  0x00005555555a1955 in ?? ()
#8  0x000055555558e9b6 in ?? ()
#9  0x000055555558bfa2 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007ffff6cb9830 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55555558a8c0, argc=1, 
    argv=0x7fffffffdde8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffddd8)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:291
#11 0x000055555558bfe9 in ?? ()
```

Comment: we talking about  nedit/xenial 1:5.6a-3 amd64
  powerful, customizable, Motif based text editor - installed with apt from official repository. right ?